# Content data in google marker infowindow not displaying correctly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am noticing strange behavior with `infowindow.setContent()`. The following line displays correctly:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>News Cafe - Rivonia</strong></div>');
```

Yet the following:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>News Cafe - Sandton</strong></div>');
```

cuts the Sandton bit off. Any ideas why this is the case?

when I call `infowindow.getContent()` in both cases I get the correct result. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or a snapshot? What do you mean it cuts it a bit off?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response [alkis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138559/alkis). but it all seems to have sorted itself out. everything displays as expected. still not sure what the cause for the issue was. maybe I was just tired and starting to see things.